# Node.js express: access application config from required modules

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a large Node.js Express API to build, so I want to make sure my solution architecture is stable and scalable.

The routes are defined each in its own separate file and stored in /routes folder. There's an index.js file as well, where all of the child routes are registered to the master router.

There's an application configuration file /config/app.js:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    configVar: 123
  },
  test: {
    configVar: 456
  },
  production: {
    configVar: 789
  },
}
```

The config object is loaded in the main application index.js file:

```
const path      = require("path");
const env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config    = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config', 'app.js'))[env];
```

Now that I have the config object, I'd like to pass it down to whatever consumer. For Express app it's mostly the routes. Loading the config repeatedly in each module would be kind of redundant. So I have set up my main routes module (/routes/index.js) as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = {
  init: function(config) {
    router.use('/test', require('./test').init(config));
    return router;
  }
}
```

And the /test route (/routes/test.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = {
  init: function(config) {
    router.post("/", function(req, res) {
      res.send('hello world');
    });
    return router;
  }
}
```

I also like that with this structure I can mock the config object when testing the routes. My question is, if this can be considered a good pattern for Express application, or perhaps there is some convention to follow.

Comment: This should work well. Only one thing that might not be cool and that's your configuration is part of the code, which might not be something you want. You can use `rc` for this though.

Comment: What do you mean that configuration is part of the code? That config file is executed JavasScript and thus it can contain expressions? I consider that an advantage rather than weakness. Of course, it could be a json file and loaded respectively.

Comment: Part of the code, as in checked into version control. If your configuration contains passwords and things that should be secure, you might not want to have that in version control. All I'm saying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat and many more ways to setup an express project.

The one thing that jumps out at me as a good thing to change is your configuration method. Your approach makes total sense, but there's a module called [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) which works in much the same way you've illustrated but you won't need to list every option for every environment.

Using this module you can have a `default.json` file which contains all of your base configurations. You can then override it with a file which matches the name of your environment such as `development` or `test` without having to do it by hand.

More importantly, it will also let you map from your applications configurations to Environment Variables. You very rarely want to store your applications configuration values in the codebase itself, especially when we're talking API keys and secrets. The last thing you want to do is commit API keys / secrets into version control. The config module linked above will allow you to define environment variable mappings which means you can feed them in via the systems environment variables instead.

I should note finally that there are many modules which act in a similar way to config and they all function slightly differently. You might also want to consider [nconf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf) which is also a brilliant module.

Comment: Thanks, I'll study the config package. Indeed it makes sense to use something that has all features built in. But as for the config files, it's just a common sense that you don't commit them in version control. I backup them separately, and commit an inactive config file to show the structure.

Comment: @Passiday, that's great! If this answered your question then would you mind ticking it as correct for future readers?